# Parent and Child Window Communication in Qt - Child Window opens twice

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have two windows, one parent and one child. In parent window, I have a Next button, which onClick()'ed, opens up child window, but in my case two child windows are opening, what is the mistake am doing!?

Here are my codes:

**.h files**

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <info.h>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void setSignals();

private slots:
    void process();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*info.h*

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class info;
}

class info : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    info(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~info();

protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::info *ui;
};

#endif // INFO_H
```

**.cpp files**

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setSignals();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui->retranslateUi(this);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::setSignals(){
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(process()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
}

void MainWindow::process(){
        info *i;
        i = new info;
        this -> hide();
        i -> show();
}
```

*info.cpp*

```
#include "info.h"
#include "ui_info.h"

info::info(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::info)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

info::~info()
{
    delete ui;
}

void info::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui->retranslateUi(this);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Show your *process()* function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, here was the problem:

In designer header file i.e., in ui_mainwindow.h, I have:

`QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), MainWindow, SLOT(process()));
 QObject::connect(pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), MainWindow, SLOT(close()));`

and in the source file i.e., mainwindow.cpp in `setSignals()`, I have again stated:

```
void MainWindow::setSignals()
{
connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(process()));
connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
}
```

So with the two connects, we get two calls to `process()` , we have to comment anyone to show only one child window. That's it :-)